# sceneDidLoad being called twice?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, ios10

Using Xcode 8, swift 3 and I create a iOS application using the game template with entities enabled. I notice I was seeing double node count for some initial sprites even though I only used addChild once.

I added

```
override func sceneDidLoad() {
print(#function) ... }
```

to the code and no idea why this is being called twice.

log file...

```
2016-09-20 10:21:31.482 MMDecon1[3295:791435] SKUtil.m: MGGetBoolAnswer is not available in the simulator.
sceneDidLoad()
sceneDidLoad()
```

I added

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {..}
```

and put my initialisation code in here as a temporary fix.

Does any one know why sceneDidLoad() is being fired twice with the default game app code using entities?

Comment: Because xcode sets up a dummy version of the scene first, then the real scene. No idea why, Apple says that it is working correctly

Comment: Where did you find that out? The comment for `sceneDidLoad` says `"this is the recommended place to perform one-time setup"`

Comment: When I submitted a bug report a long time ago about it,  then again any bug report I sent they have claimed it is working correctly,  no idea why I bother submitting bugs.

Comment: You shouldn't be seeing double the nodes,  it should be destroying the dummy scene instantly

Comment: I am seeing the same thing.  My only theory is that it has to do with me using a Segue in Storyboard editor...that's the only remanning possibility that I see.  Not sure why, though.  The didMoveToView:(SKView *)view workaround works, though - thank you.

Comment: I was having the same problem with programmatically created nodes. My node count was double what it was supposed to be and moving everything to 'didMoveToView' worked, however, I am wondering whether it there are any side effects (otherwise why would they have created scene did load in the first place.) caused by moving everything to 'didMoveToView'

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I am seeing double too.  Try making a fresh sprite kit project, and replace `GameScene` with this, and watch the madness:      
class GameScene: SKScene {
    var box:SKSpriteNode!
    override func sceneDidLoad() {
        box = SKSpriteNode(color: .red, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
        addChild(box)
    }
    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        box.position.x += 0.2
        box.position.y -= 0.2
    }
}

Comment: @mogelbuster, yeah, apparently the scene does not die if you add the nodes during the didLoad phase,  I recommend moving code to the did move to view phase

Comment: This was a bug and has been fixed in the iOS 11.0 beta.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, sceneDidLoad is only called one time. However, if a memory warning is sent then UIViewController releases its scene and sets it to nil if the view controller isn't visible. The next time that the scene appears the view controller will reload the scene and call sceneDidLoad again.

You have to assume that sceneDidLoad can be called multiple times.

Implement didReceiveMemoryWarning and log or set a breakpoint to see what is happening.